# Solution Explorer Context Menu Too Long

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Ok, so I installed plenty of useful extensions from Extension Manager in Visual Studio 2010.
I really like them but now my context menu in solution explorer is way too long.
So long in fact that I have to scroll down/up using little arrows which is really annoying.

Any solution to that anyone?

Comment: Ouch, the candy-store effect.  Get familiar with Tools + Customize to modify the menu.

Comment: :) What do you mean by 'customize to modify the menu' ?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that when you right-click on an entity within the Solution Explorer, the resulting context menu is so loaded down with options, extensions, menus, lists and levels that you have to start scrolling around to get anywhere.

The solution is to declutter that context menu by removing unneccessary items. This can be achieved through the **Commands** tab of the **Tools -> Customize** dialog. Specifically, click on the **Commands** tab, and select the **Context Menu** button to start customizing anything and (almost) everything to do with those context menus.

Many of the entities within the Solution Explorer have some sort of representation here; the biggest issue you have will be finding the *right* place to start customizing.

For example, I have a method of Source Control integrated within the Visual Studio environment which causes 7 new menu items to appear when I right-click on a project (Check In, Check Out, Get Latest Version, etc). I do all of my source controlling outside of Visual Studio, so these menu items are just clutter to me. I go to **Project and Solution Context Menu | Project** and delete anything and everything related to Source Control. Now, when I right-click on a project, none of those options appear in the menu.

Comment: +1 for removing items in Customize, but I believe the OP not only facing with unnecessary items but also the list does not fully utilize screen size. my context menu only using half of the screen with very small up and down arrow to scroll the menu because it decide to show above/below the mouse pointer, if above it will show from top of screen until the mouse position, but not down until the bottom of screen.